# Laravel - show exception if model/row doesn't exist or soft deleted

Tags: php, laravel, exception, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Lets say i have a model called "Manufacturer" with a controller which has a show method

```
public function show($id)
{
    $manufacturer = json_decode( $this->manufacturer->find($id) );
    return view('viewManufacturer', compact('manufacturer'));
}
```

And a Eloquent-repository with a find method

```
public function find($id)
{
    return Manufacturer::find($id)->toJson();
}
```

**Now if a model doesn't exist or is softdeleted it gives me a fatal exception**

```
FatalErrorException in ManufacturerRepository.php line 22:
Call to a member function toJson() on null
```

How do i set an exception, so instead of the default error page it shows a custom error page with something like, "Manufacturer not found".

**EDIT:** 
Well i actually tried that, but it returns an error. The above mentioned query was just for demonstration, in actual i have another model called vehicle. And Manufacturer has one to many relationship with Vehicle.

```
public function find($id, $columns1 = array('*'), $columns2 = array('*'))
{
    return Manufacturer::with(['vehicles' => function($q) use ($columns2){
           $q->select($columns2);
    }])->get($columns1)->find($id)->toJson();
}
```

So if i replace find with findOrFail it spits an error saying `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::findOrFail()`

Comment: `return Manufacturer::findOrFail($id)->toJson();` you could catch this with 404 error page if i am not wrong.

Comment: please checkout my edit with the actual code, findOrFail is not working with relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of **find()** method call **findOrFail()** - if the model is not found this method will throw **ModelNotFoundException** which should result in **404** page in your application.

**UPDATE:**

In your second example replace:

```
return Manufacturer::with(['vehicles' => function($q) use ($columns2){
  $q->select($columns2);
}])->get($columns1)->find($id)->toJson();
```

with

```
return Manufacturer::with(['vehicles' => function($q) use ($columns2){
  $q->select($columns2);
}])->findOrFail($id, $columns1)->toJson();
```

Comment: Yes, that ideally should have solved the problem. But i am using relationships as well. Can you please checkout my actual code in the edit.

Comment: I've updated the answer. You were calling findOrFail on the result collection instead of query builder.

Comment: Thankyou so much, Thats perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show custom view instead of 404 page.

```
public function find($id) {
    $manufacturer = Manufacturer::find($id)->first();
    if($manufacturer) {
       return $manufacturer->toJson();
    }
    return false;
}

public function show($id) {        
    $manufacturer = $this->manufacturer->find($id);
    if($manufacturer) {
        $manufacturer = json_decode($manufacturer);
        return view('viewManufacturer', compact('manufacturer'));
     }
     else {
        return view('viewManufacturerNotFound');
     }
}
```

Btw, why do you use `toJson()` and then `json_decode()`?

Without json encoding/decoding:

```
public function find($id) {
    return Manufacturer::find($id)->first(['column1','column2']);        
}

public function show($id) {        
    $manufacturer = $this->manufacturer->find($id);
    if($manufacturer) {            
        return view('viewManufacturer', compact('manufacturer'));
     }
     else {
        return view('viewManufacturerNotFound');
     }
}
```

Comment: yes i know it sounds stupid, but if i dont use toJson(), then all the model hidden fields are shown as well.

Comment: What does 'hidden fields' mean?

Comment: by hidden fields, i mean : 
protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token']; in the model

Comment: I updated my answer. You can specify required column names in the array as parameter for `first()` function.